# Remove in Jquery divs with draggables and resizables

Tags: jquery, draggable, resizable

i have a question:
When you make a div as draggable and resizable and later when you want remove, i need destroy draggable and resizables? The same for droppables.

Example:

```
$("element").draggable("destroy").resizable("destroy").remove();
```

or only need?:

```
$("element").remove();
```

The same for when you want replace html of a div that have elements with draggables:

```
$(".parent .elements").draggable("destroy").resizable("destroy").parent().html(newHtml).find(".newsElements").draggable().resizable();
```

or only need?:

```
$(".parent").html(newHtml).find(".newsElements").draggable().resizable();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just try. Or you cant try becouse of... ?

Comment: If you change your e-mail to the account you used when asking this question, I can merge your accounts and give you ownership of your question again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.class')
    .html('bla')
    .remove();
```

Thats all.